# perl configuration and blocks

Tags: perl, configuration

I am trying to do the configuration file in perl using 
[`Config::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Simple)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Config::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

#$cfg = new Config::Simple('new.conf');

$cfg = new Config::Simple(syntax => 'ini');

$cfg->param("Dialer Onboard.user", "user1");
$cfg->param("Dialer Onboard.pass", "pass1");
$cfg->param("Dialer External.user", "user2");
$cfg->param("Dialer External.pass", "pass2");

$cfg->write("new.conf");
$cfg->read('new.conf');

$user = $cfg->param("Dialer Onboard.user");
print "----" . "$user";
```

And the `new.conf` file would be

```
[Dialer External]
pass=pass2
user=user2

[Dialer Onboard]
pass=pass1
user=user1
```

For the section or block information, I am using the function `get_block()` like this

```
my $config = Config::Simple->new("new.conf")->get_block("Dialer Onboard");
print Dumper $config;
```

This will give me the output like this

```
$VAR1 = {
    'pass' => 'pass1',
    'user' => 'user1'
};
```

Is there any way to get the only the names of all blocks?

Now I am getting only the number of blocks which is

```
my $config = Config::Simple->new("new.conf")->get_block();
print Dumper $config;
```

The output would be

```
$VAR1 = 2;
```

Comment: It's annoying that the Config::Simple documentation uses the "new Class" syntax. Although it looks familiar to users of other OO languages, it can potentially lead to hard-to-find bugs. See the section on [Indirect Object Notation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Invoking-Class-Methods). You should use `$cfg = Config::Simple0>new(syntax => 'ini')` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `get_block()` in scalar context; that's why you are getting the number of blocks. Use it in list context to get the names of the blocks.

Try this:

```
my @config = Config::Simple->new("new.conf")->get_block();
print Dumper \@config;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Dialer Onboard',
          'Dialer External'
        ];
```